# Exposing domain model in GRPC IDL

Tags: kubernetes, spring-rest, grpc-java

We have our existing domain model consumed using spring REST. The services are currently hosted on Kuberenetes and all east-west and north-south communication is done using http/1.1. We are planning migrate some of the services to GRPC on http/2.0. With GRPC the need for implementing IDL  introduces some form of code duplication in both domain model (Java) and IDL (protobuf). Is this not an anti pattern, where representation of underlying domain exists in more than one place. Is there a way to avoid it.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on your Kubernetes set-up? Which version of Kubernetes do you use?

Comment: @MikolajS. 1.21

Comment: Please provide details on how exactly you´ve configured your Kubernetes cluster. Is it bare-metal or hosted on some platform?